# Simple newsletter not diplaying images

Tags: media, emails

I am using [Simplenews](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjiz9Of6f_HAhVGnJQKHSjaCjc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fsimplenews&usg=AFQjCNFz-bK_CjBh8e5DujVJ7g4vZLNq_Q&sig2=rbL8z_AUwMTFVmFNwVfYlg) module for sending newsletter to users. I have created a view and the view will be the newsletter body. The view has title and images. When I send email to users, images in view are breaking. But other iamges such and footer images are displaying. When inspected the URL `itok=''` is missing from the image. I am using [Mime Mail](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjmjYen6v_HAhXFmpQKHb_jCDs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fmimemail&usg=AFQjCNFE_VSjlW3RA0wzoNFfnU9gFIosVQ&sig2=hOkhOGDndbwiSv0T8HnCaQ&bvm=bv.102829193,d.dGo) for email sending. Is any configuration to be made in Mime Mail for displaying the images. Thank You

Comment: Please confirm that you are using absolute path of image?

Answer (score 0):

Please set **E-mail format** Plain Text to Full HTML in Mime Mail Settings

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue few days back. My images breaks in the email. After searching, I found the solution in [drupal issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2552613). After apply the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/mimemail_broken_images_urls-2552613-8.patch) mentioned in [#9](https://www.drupal.org/node/2552613#comment-10311001), image break issue resolved for me. I don't know whether it is correct approach there may be some other approach but it solves my problem. Thank You.